# Does Salesforce allow create custom report types on tooling objects?

Tags: reporting, custom-report-type

I am interested in creating a custom report on tooling objects (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/reference_objects_list.htm) however when I go to Reports->Report Types, I am unable to see these objects. How can I create a report on tables that I can run SOQL on but are not available in the GUI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reporting engine does not allow these types of objects. The only way to get information is through SOQL.